# rake assets:precompile error: File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

There are a handful of of similar questions in SO, but none of them seem to contain a solution to my problem.

Simply put, why am I getting the following error and what can I do to solve it?

```
$ rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production
rake aborted!
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-clubicle.css.erb.
Load path: ~/Clubicle/Source/clubicle
  (in ~/Clubicle/Source/clubicle/app/assets/stylesheets/public_portal.css.scss)
```

There is nothing odd about the @import statement being questioned.

```
@import 'bootstrap-clubicle.css.erb';
```

The bootstrap-clubicle.css.erb file does exist, in the stylesheets directory.

I am running Rails 3.1.1 on OSX 10.6.8.

It is also worth noting that I am getting the same error when deploying my app on EngineYard.

Comment: I sometimes get this when permissions are not set for the user running the rake task.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The permissions all appear to be fine. There is only one user on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fine support people at [EngineYard](http://engineyard.com) finally pinpointed the cause of the problem. I had files that were required in application.css (using `//= require`) that were also included elsewhere (using `@import`). The double import was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After several painful hours' struggle with this problem, I just want to add another solution that worked for me.

My application.css file looked like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */

@import "base";
```

Notice, I took out:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

because I was importing another Sass file using the @import directive.

I had to remove the entire comment — not just the requires to get Sass to find my @import "base". Once I did that the import was found and the app precompiled.